# Bootstrap collapse close

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hi I used this bootstrap collapse code, I want this collapse to close once the user clicks outside the panel. I tried using this script but it still did not help me with what I was expecting. Could someone please help.
**the code**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewmore" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Open this 
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="viewmore">
  <div class="card card-body">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

**the script**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.panel-body')) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');        
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't write jQuery for Bootstrap's core components. That's the purpose of the custom attributes. Do you have the library properly loaded?

Comment: I agree with the above, you need to fire the bootstrap event for the collapse or it will either not work or forget its own state, though I do see you are using the collapse method.

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes.

Comment: And if you must do things manually, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#methods.

Comment: I do have the rest of the attributes loaded properly, on click of the button the collapse opens, and after clicking the same button the collapse closes. I  need to find a way to close the collapse automatically once the user interacts with other elements on the screen. Sorry for the inconvenience, but thank you for your replies!